# Is it possible to add same existing dom structure after clicking button jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom, element

I have ten textfields in one `div`. I want to add another ten textfields with same name and `class` and `id`.

Is it possible to reuse the above DOM structure or do I have to again create ten textboxes with jQuery and append them?

I have tried creating and appending but I am trying to reuse already existing DOM structure instead of creating.

Comment: You must not add fields with the same id. Id  attribute has to be unique

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In jQuery, you can clone then append to DOM

```
$('.selector').clone().appendTo('.container');
```

Due to duplication, you should use class selector instead of ID